# No argument passed with Android Hilt

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm, dagger-hilt

I have a fragment:

```
class PingFragment : Fragment(), ViewRenderer<StartingState> {
    private val viewModel: PingFragmentViewModel by viewModels()
```

A ViewModel :

```
class PingFragmentViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private var pingRepository: PingRepository) : ViewModel() {
```

A repository:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class PingRepository @Inject constructor(@ActivityContext var context: Context) {
```

When I Start my Application, I have this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.ping.android.fragment.PingFragmentViewModel> has
> no zero argument constructor

WHat I can do to tell at Hilt to pass my repo as argument to my VM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `@AndroidEntryPoint` to your fragment class